# How can I protect my rug from being dented by table stands?

Tags: carpet, table, protection

I have one rug (rug on top of carpet in my apartment) in the living room where a center table rests, and one rug under the dining table. Each of the rugs have developed dents at the point of contact with the table stands, (due to the pressure from stands).

Is there any way to protect the rug from denting?

Answer (score 1):

Put something under the table legs to diffuse the pressure to a wider area.  Something like the circle disc (2 inch variety) furniture moving pads would work for something like this.

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the disc size required to completely (or nearly so) disperse the weight of the table? In my experience, the furniture moving discs make a slightly larger but less deep indentation.

Comment: That is a math question.  Maybe for another stackexchange.   You have four legs, your table is a certain weight, and the disks are a certain size.  The problem is it is hard to get a calculation for the compression of the "rug" under it...  If you have a 1000 pound table supported by 4 legs with 1/2" settings then you have a force of 318  lbs/inch(squared) on the rug - in 4 small spots.  Change that to 2 inch discs and you are at about 20 lbs/inch (squared).  Your discs need to be solid enough that they distribute the weight evenly though.

Answer (score -1):

The more plush the carpet, the more obvious the marks left behind when you move the sofa. Since leaving furniture out of the room isn't a practical option, you can use several preventive methods to keep those carpet dents to a minimum. Small pieces of scrap carpet, furniture coasters or an area rug all help prevent those carpet craters.